# Online Status for Multiple Users

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I was able to do online status but works only for one user. When I login, it shows all users on users.php online even when they are offline. 
Here is the Status Code:

```
session_start();
include_once 'db_connect.php' ;
if(isset($_SESSION['users'])) {
$setLogged= mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `lastlogin` = '$last' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['users']."'") or die(mysql_error());
}
$last = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:s'));
$loggedtime = time() - 300; // 5 minutes
    if($last > $loggedtime) { 
       echo '<font color="green" size="3px">online</font>';
    } else {
       echo '<font color="red" size="3px">offline</font>';
}
?>
```

I need help on how to make it work for multiple users.
Thanks.  ;)

Comment: `$last` is always greater than `$loggedtime`

Comment: you're always testing `$last = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:s'));` which is the server time at that moment with `time()-300` this will always be true... you have to test last_login of users that you have in the database

Comment: @CodeBird correct, and that needs to happen before the OP updates the lastlogin field in the database with the current time - although as the code stands, `$last` is uninitialised at the point the update is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something like this:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE last_login>NOW()-INTERVAL 30 MIN");
while($array=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      //Do something with the id's or the info you get for user who have there last login
      //in the last 30mins
}
```

As @Crisp says in the comment above your query for last_login should be updated too, you can use mysql now() function like this:

```
$setLogged= mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `lastlogin` = NOW() WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['users']."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Note you have to stop using mysql_* as these functions are deprecated, start using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)**

Comment: Thanks CodeBird. I'm a newbie

Comment: I have tried to do as directed but I dont know the syntax on how to go about it. This is my first year in php. Help!! Pls !!!